# Post string and bytearray to server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I have done POSTING and GETing from server using string post data, but now i have the next WebService:

submitFeedback(String token, String subject, String body, byte[] photo, byte[] video);

```
private void PostFeedbackData()
    {
        if (GS.online != true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(GS.translations["ErrorMsg0"]);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("https://****/feedback");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        }
    }
    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

        // Create the post data
        string postData = "";

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            postData = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"getUserSchedule\", \"params\":[" + "\"" + (App.Current as App).UserToken + "\",\"" + FeedbackTitle.Text + "\",\"" + FeedbackContent.Text + "\",\"" + imageBytes + "\"], \"id\": 1}";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Add the post data to the web request
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the web request
            myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
        });

    }
```

**Look at post data - it is a string, i can't place there imageBytes array. How to do it?**

Comment: Did you try converting the byte[] to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for using HttpWebRequest ?

I am asking that because i think that the correct way of sending files to a service is by multipartform data. With HttpWebRequest you have to manually implement that.

Here is an example that is using Microsoft's HttpClient that might work for you:

```
public async Task<string> submitFeedback(String token, String subject, String body, byte[] photo, byte[] video) {
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(); 

    // Some APIs do not support quotes in boundary field
    foreach (var param in content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Where(param => param.Name.Equals("boundary")))
        param.Value = param.Value.Replace("\"", String.Empty);

    var tok = new StringContent(token);
    content.Add(tok, "\"token\"");
    var sub = new StringContent(subject);
    content.Add(tok, "\"subject\"");

    // Add the Photo 
    var photoContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(photo));
    photoContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "\"photo\"",
        FileName = "\"photoname.jpg\""
    };
    photoContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
    content.Add(photoContent);

    // Add the video
    var videoContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(video));
    videoContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "\"video\"",
        FileName = "\"videoname.jpg\""
    };
    videoContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("video/mp4");
    content.Add(videoContent);

    HttpResponseMessage resp;

    try {           
        resp = await client.PostAsync("SERVER_URL_GOES_HERE", content);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "EXCEPTION ERROR";
    }

    if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return resp.StatusCode.ToString();
    }

    var reponse = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return reponse;
}
```

Change accordingly.
Note: HttpClient is also using HttpWebRequest under the hood.
Also I don't think its a good idea to have the UI thread making the request. That makes no sense since you are blocking the interface and making the async theory useless.